# Range to mail body excel VBA but not showing full range

Tags: html, excel, vba, email, outlook

I have the below code which is trying to help me put an excel range into the body of an email.

The macros is able to automatically display the mail with the recipients however, it doesn't capture the whole 'contents' of the range and I see the body of the text in my range cut vertically off. Not sure if anyone can advise please.

```
Sub Email()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim mainfont As String
Dim headerfont As String
Dim subheaderfont As String
Dim closemain As String
Dim closeheader As String
Dim closesubheader As String

Dim Ash As Worksheet

Set Ash = ActiveSheet
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'define variables html code

Set rng1 = Range("Body").Cells

'construct email

With OutMail
.To = Range("To").Value
.cc = Range("Cc").Value
.Subject = Range("Subject").Value
.HTMLBody = _
RangetoHTML(rng1) & _
.Display

End With

End Sub

Function htm(str As String, frm As String)

'Set font parameters for body text

mainfont = "<FONT face='Calibri' size=2 color=#000000>"
headerfont = "<FONT face='Calibri' size=2 color=#000000><b><u>"
subheaderfont = "<FONT face='Calibri' size=2 color=#000000><u>"
closemain = "</font>"
closesubheader = "</font></u>"
closeheader = "</font></b></u>"


If frm = "h" Then htm = headerfont & str & closeheader
If frm = "m" Then htm = mainfont & str & closemain
If frm = "s" Then htm = subheaderfont & str & closesubheader


End Function

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
.Cells(1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
On Error Resume Next
.DrawingObjects.Visible = True
.DrawingObjects.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
Filename:=TempFile, _
Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
.Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
"align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I have a working similar code that do this task , If you wish I can post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the word editor directly (no need to generate html)

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim mainfont As String
Dim headerfont As String
Dim subheaderfont As String
Dim closemain As String
Dim closeheader As String
Dim closesubheader As String

Dim Ash As Worksheet

Set Ash = ActiveSheet
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
OutApp.Session.Logon

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

'define variables html code

Set rng1 = Range("Body").Cells

'construct email

With OutMail
.Display
.To = Range("To").Value
.CC = Range("Cc").Value
.Subject = Range("Subject").Value
rng1.Copy
.GetInspector.WordEitor.Range(0, 0).Paste

End With

End Sub
```